# Use images as data points in line graph - Android

Tags: java, android, graph, android-graphview

I am new to Android Development and I have to make line graph.
The graph I am trying to make is very customized i.e. using images as the data point.

There are lots of open source libraries but I cant use images as data points and they should be clickable.

**Chart I am trying to make**

[image: Chart I am trying to make]

Comment: Please comment the reason for down voting

Comment: I didn't down vote but I would guess that the person down voted as your question is too broad.

Comment: No, really. I want to know why the question got an **up**vote (wait, it's actually **3** upvotes!!!). **No code, no effort, no nothing... only requesting for code or libraries**... and someone **up**votes! You serious?!

Comment: I was onto the same problem, atleast some one attempted to ask. And I upvoted so that other may know that the question is good in context. It is usual paractive @BobMalooga

Comment: @SyedAliSalman No. The question is NOT good. The idea might be. But this site is not about sharing ideas.

Comment: I used achartengine library, but I cannot modify or customaries the chart according to my requirements. @BobMalooga

Comment: You have the source. Feel free to modify it and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

i'm to late in answering this question but i have done recently this type of work using  [MPChartAndroid](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

> this is the simple code to set icons you can check complete example at this [link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

```
     ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            float val = (float) (Math.random() * range) - 30;
            values.add(new Entry(i, val, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star)));
        }

        LineDataSet set1;
set1 = LineDataSet(values, "")

            set1.setDrawIcons(true)
chart.setData(data);
```